# PHP - accessing a non-class function inside a class

Tags: php, function, class, constructor, member

**My Try:** There is `$getSomeData` function in a file called bradpitt.php. Its a simple function. Which is not inside a class. Where I have another file name jolie.php. This file is having a class. Where I am trying to access `$getSomeData()`in that file.

**CoolPlugin.php**

```
class CoolPlugin extends plugin
{
    const COOLLIST = 'properties/coolBoy.json';

    public function getSomeData () {
        return DataUtil::readDataFile(self::COOLLIST);
    }
```

**bradpitt.php** (Non Class File - a simple function)

```
$getSomeData = function(){
    $plugin = new \simulator\CoolPlugin();
    return $plugin->getSomeData();
};
```

**jolie.php**

```
include_once 'bradpitt.php';
class Jolie{
    public $getSomeData;
    public function __construct(){
        global $getSomeData;
        $this->$getSomeData();
    }
}
```

**output.php**

```
include_once 'jolie.php';
$joiliePage = new Jolie();
var_dump($joiliePage->getSomeData);

ERROR:
Notice: Undefined variable: joiliePage in output.php on line 173
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in output.php on line 173
**NULL**
```

How to invoke and access a simple function (having a return as an object) inside another class in PHP?

What I doing wrong where it returns NULL?

Comment: For starters: `joliePage` != `joiliePage`. Also, are you including `jolie.php` in `output.php`?

Comment: @FirstOne - sorry! and corrected typo and added include `jolie.php` in `output.php`.

Comment: Your code in https://3v4l.org/G9T0H should have a return as an object in CoolPlugin.php. My ultimate goal is to print `coolBoy.json` data in `jolie.php`. If I do a direct print in `output.php` like `$see = $getSomeData(); var_dump($see);` I am getting the JSON data printed but If try accessing and printing through `joile.php` its not happening. *How I should do the same in OO way?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is full of issues.

```
var_dump($joiliePage->getSomeData);

ERROR:
Notice: Undefined variable: joiliePage in output.php on line 173
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in output.php on line 173
**NULL**
```

Assuming is line 173 is the one listed above, both error messages tell the same thing: the variable `$joiliePage` was not initialized (and the interpreter considers its value is `NULL`).

Don't get fooled by the fact that PHP classifies them as "Notices". They are notices from the interpreter's point of view (it cannot find a variable) but they are errors for your code as it cannot continue successfully.

---

```
include_once 'bradpitt.php';
class Jolie{
    public $getSomeData;
    public function __contruct(){
        global $getSomeData;
        $this->$getSomeData()
    }
}
```

The function is called `__contruct()` but you probably want it to be the class' [**constructor**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). It is not the constructor and it is not called automatically by the interpreter because it doesn't have the correct name. The name of the constructor is `__construct()`. Notice there is an "s" in the middle that is missing in your code.

The method `__contruct()` declares the global variable `$getSomeData`. **If** the file `bradpitt.php` is successfully included (it may fail with a warning without breaking the script if the file does not exists) then the `$getSomeData` symbol refers to the variable with the same name defined in file `bradpitt.php`.

However, the call `$this->$getSomeData()` doesn't refer to this global variable. It uses the class' property with the same name, which is initialized. This code won't run.

In order to call the function stored in the global variable `$getSomeData`, the code should read:

```
public function __construct(){
    global $getSomeData;
    $getSomeData();
}
```

Also notice that the statement is missing a semicolon at the end and produces a syntax error. Your class' definition is incorrect, it doesn't compile and objects of type `Jolie` cannot be created.

Comment: thank you for your effort.. and `__construct` is not an issue. I am accepting your answer for `$this->$getSomeData() doesn't refer to this global variable`. Which is were it went wrong.